# Decomposition of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Given two open overlapping sets $\Omega_1$, $\Omega_2$ and an analytic function $f$ on $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2$, how does one prove that there are analytic functions $g_1$ on $\Omega_1$ and $g_2$ on $\Omega_2$ such that $f=g_1+g_2$ on $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2$ ?

Comment: In what sense can it be said that $f=g_1+g_2$ when the LHS is only defined on the intersection? Do we need to be mindful that, in the equation, each RHS term is to be regarded as defined only on the shared intersection? (This could be written: $f=\left.g_1\right|_\Omega+\left.g_2\right|_\Omega$, where $\Omega=\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2$.) I'm guessing the original problem said "on the intersection" or something to that effect to qualify the sense of the RHS of the equation. Just an idea, but...do you know any ways of extending a function from the intersection to the union?

Comment: Good point, I've updated the question accordingly. One special case where it is clear how to proceed is when $\Omega_1=\{z:|z|>R>1\}$ and $\Omega_2=\{z:|z|<r<1\}$. In this case the intersection is an annulus and so $f$ can be written as a Laurent series which then naturally splits into the series of negative powers of $z$ and the series of positive powers of $z$. I'd like to know how to do this in the general situation.

Answer (score 2):

Take a smooth function $\rho:\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2\to[0,1]$ such that $\rho\equiv 0$ outside $\Omega_1$ and $\rho\equiv 1$ outside $\Omega_2$.

Now, the function $f\rho$ extends to $\Omega_2$ and the function $f(1-\rho)$ extends to $\Omega_1$, both as smooth functions; we would like to modify them so that the sum remains unchanged but they both become holomorphic.

The first condition implies that we want to define
$$g_1=u+f(1-\rho)$$
$$g_2=-u+f\rho$$
for a smooth function $u$ defined on $\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2$.

The second condition implies that $\overline{\partial}g_1=\overline{\partial}g_2=0$; i.e.
$$\overline{\partial}u=f\overline{\partial}\rho$$
we note that $f\overline{\partial\rho}$ is a well define $(0,1)$-form on $\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2$.

Solving the $\overline{\partial}$-equation, we get a smooth function $u$ which solves our problem, so that $g_1$ and $g_2$ become holomorphic.

**NB:** This is just an adaptation of the solution of the Cousin I problem to the case with only $2$ open sets in $\mathbb{C}$ (where on every open domain we can solve the Cauchy-Riemann equation). So, if you assume to know that Cousin I problem has a holomorphic solution, the whole exercise becomes trivial.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using tools from classical complex analysis?

Comment: Sorry, what is classical complex analysis, for you? Because for me the Cauchy-Riemann equation is at the very core of it.

Comment: My issues is with the $\bar\partial$ equation, it is usually not covered in the introductory graduate complex analysis course.

Comment: Was this given to you as an exercise in such a course? If so, what were the topics treated just before?

Comment: This problem is from the chapter on Mittag-Leffler Theorems and Weierstrass/Hadamard Factorizations.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got back at you because I really have no clue on how to do it for two generic open connected sets ... if you don't have any particular geometric structure (like in your example with annuli) I don't really see how some "global" results like the ones you mentioned could be of use...